# Can I Convert my xamarin ui tests project from .net framework 4.7.2 to .net core 3.0?

Tags: .net-core, xamarin.forms, .net-framework-version, xamarin.uitest

I have a xamarin ui tests project and I Want to convert him .net framework 4.7.2 to .net core 3.0
is it possible?

Comment: I've never tried one of those projects. If you rt-click on project in solution explorer, click properties, is there a framework version in any of the property tabs?

Comment: .Net framework from 4 to 4.8

Comment: Is that a dropdown?  If so, what happens if you make a copy of your project (in case something goes wrong), and select a different version? Is .net core 3.0 listed as an option?

Comment: no it's not giving me the option

Comment: Maybe its not installed? Have you used it for other projects? If not, do "Tools / Get Tools and Features" (which runs VS installer, in a mode that allows adding features).  Tab "Individual Components", Checkmark ".NET Core 3.1 Runtime" (or .NET Core 3.0, if you want exactly that), AND "Development Tools plus .NET Core 2.1" (OR "Web Development Tools plus...)

Comment: it is installed

Comment: It looks like Microsoft's plan is to [move everything to .Net 5](https://www.clariontech.com/blog/microsoft-announces-.net-5-a-brief-overview). Is that an option?